# Azure FILE SYSTEM STORAGE Quota upgrade

Tags: wordpress, azure

I have a number (~20) of student websites running WordPress on Azure, 
They love the ease of setting it up for themselves. However we've recently maxed out the 1GB limit of the shared tier and upgraded to Basic. I was expecting the File System Storage to increase to 10GB but an hour or so later it still hasn't increased. We're still getting:

USAGE WARNING
One or more of your usage quotas are approaching their limits. You can upgrade now to lift quota limitations.

and the file system storage is showing on 1024MB, I expected this to be kind of instant, I cannot find a link on line explaining how long it should take so any pointers welcome....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade it your self. It wont be automatically since it will increase the amount you are being charged. Unles you configure it to be automatic, in that case you will have to turn on scalability.